# Help finding c api

Tags: c, api, gtk, report

Im coding a simple c/gtk+ app connected to a mysql database. The gui and db code is done, now I need to make some reports based on database data, I thought the easier way to do this is by using an api that would let me output the data to a Excel or openoffice spreadsheet,PDF would be helpful too. The problem is dont find any.

Comment: An idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV_application_support

Comment: @steve thought of that, but how do I add format to a csv.

Comment: I also thought of using cairo to render to a PDF but that would be highly inefficient because of my data being mostly text.

Comment: I will try to be a little more especific with what I need. I need to output a few rows from my dB to a spreadsheet format Excel-compatible plus basic formating and PDF creation would be helpful too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cairo is the way: surely it is not inefficient... maybe too low level. If you report is mostly text, I'd render to the cairo context with [pango](http://www.pango.org/), yet part of the GTK+ stack.

Comment: @fetasail I didn't know I could combine cairo+pango. I've used cairo in the past but only for drawing. Thanks for the answer.